# Adding a static picture to a Folium map

Tags: python

I'd like to add a add a static picture to my Folium map. I tried following the instructions [found](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1093) [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1093), but for some reason things go wrong.

It works well when I use the exact same url (from the second hyperlink, above), but when I replace it with my own, an image with a "?" is added to the map. For instance, I tried replacing the url with

```
https://imgur.com/a/odmnKy6
```

or with

```
https://github.com/maxmuller100/ideas/blob/master/Screenshot%202021-05-30%20at%2015.34.50.jpg
```

Both links contain the same image I uploaded. However, they're not shown in my map once I upload (either of) by putting the url in the code.

**Question**: What should I do differently to properly insert the image into the Folium map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs you provide in your post do not point to an actual image, but to a website (HTML document) that contains the actual images. Therefore, Python can't display them, as it doesn't understand them (because it's trying to process them as images).

To get the images' URLs in any modern browser, you have to right-click the image whose url you want, and click on "Copy image's link" to copy them, or "Open image on a new tab" to open a new tab with the URLs of the actual images.

These URLs point to the physical image on the web server, and thus consist just of that, an image. There is no website (shuch as Imgur or Github) that is dispayed alongside them.

In your case, the URLs of your images would be:

```
https://i.imgur.com/FVB4LxT.jpg
```

and

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maxmuller100/ideas/master/Screenshot%202021-05-30%20at%2015.34.50.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know how to resize the image in Folium, by any chance?

Comment: The plugin in question (FloatImage) does not have any options for resizing (only for layout), and there doesn't seem to be a function from within Folium documentation that could resize the image (altough I have noticed that these docs are missing some functions).
Anyhow, you could always resize the image in your computer [by using GIMP, for example](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMP_Quickies/#changing-the-size-dimensions-of-an-image-scale) and then use it in Folium.